# Test my service with xUnit and asp.net core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

I would like to test my service with asp.net core and xunit.

Here's my service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}

public interface IMyService
{
    int Add(int x, int y);
}
```

I registered my service in startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

But now how can I get an instance and test my service in test project?

So far in my test project I have:

```
public class Class1
{
    IMyService myService;

    [Fact]
    public void PassingTest()
    {
        Assert.Equal(4, myService.Add(2,2));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to test?

Comment: My method which I have in MyService class

Comment: then just new up an instance and call the method under test

Comment: I've updated my post with my solution which is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New up an instance and call the method under test. No need to over complicate things.

```
public class Class1 { 

    IMyService myService = new MyService();

    [Fact]
    public void PassingTest()
    {
        Assert.Equal(4, myService.Add(2,2));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: `Workaround: add Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions to test dependencies manually` - https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/366